# Eliminate redundancies from a file using Python

Tags: python, data-processing

How to condense, i.e. eliminate redundancies from, the following data:

```
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 2673
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 23
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 459
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 346
code: RO-B, jobs: 9
code: DE-NW, jobs: 4
code: DE-BW, jobs: 3
code: DE-BY, jobs: 9
code: DE-HH, jobs: 34
code: DE-BY, jobs: 11
code: BE-BRU, jobs: 27
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 20
```

The output should be in this way:

```
GB-ENG, 3521
RO-B, 9
DE-NW, 4
DE-BW, 3
DE-HH, 34
DE-BY, 20
BE-BRU, 27
```

Described by 1 canonical representation of each code, i.e. `DE-BY`, that would represent the sum total aggregated over the numbers that are associated with each instance of that code, e.g.:

```
code: DE-BY, jobs: 11
code: DE-BY, jobs: 9
```

becomes

```
DE-BY, 20
```

at the moment I'm creating that input with this Python script:

```
import json
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

# open up the output of 'data-processing.py'
with open('job-numbers-by-location.txt') as data_file:

    # print the output to a file
    with open('phase_ii_output.txt', 'w') as output_file_:
        for line in data_file:
            identifier, name, coords, number_of_jobs = line.split("|")
            coords = coords[1:-1]
            lat, lng = coords.split(",")
            # print("lat: " + lat, "lng: " + lng)
            response = requests.get("http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivisionJSON?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&username=s.matthew.english").json()


            codes = response.get('codes', [])
            for code in codes:
                if code.get('type') == 'ISO3166-2':
                    country_code = '{}-{}'.format(response.get('countryCode', 'UNKNOWN'), code.get('code', 'UNKNOWN'))
                    if not hasNumbers( country_code ):
                        # print("code: " + country_code + ", jobs: " + number_of_jobs)
                        output_file_.write("code: " + country_code + ", jobs: " + number_of_jobs)
    output_file_.close()
```

it would probably be most efficient to include this functionality as part of that script but I've not been able to yet figure out how.

Comment: You could try using a python Counter where the key is the code and the value is the number of jobs.

Comment: instead of writing to the file you mean? what would that look like?

Comment: You could probably do this easily with only standard UNIX tools and a command line.

Comment: You are free to accept any answer of your choosing and I normally wouldn't mind that. However, you've deselected mine and accepted an answer that requires `eval` despite the fact that it's one of the worst features of Python i.e. can completely wipe your entire system? See [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). I'm interested in your logic here... I don't see how it improves on my original answer, it just happens to be newer.

Comment: It doesn't use a context manager to handle file opening (indeed the file isn't even closed at the end) and it doesn't write any output, just gives a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the text is stored in a text file, this would work

```
infile = open('redundancy.txt','r')
a= infile.readlines()
print a
d={}
for item in a:
    c=item.strip('\n')    
    b=c.split()    
    if b[1] in d :
        d[b[1]]= int(d.get(b[1]))+eval((b[3]))
    else:
        d[b[1]]=b[3]
print d
```

it would give a result :

```
{'DE-BY,': 20, 'DE-HH,': '34', 'DE-BW,': '3', 'DE-NW,': '4', 'RO-B,': '9', 'GB-ENG,': 3521, 'BE-BRU,': '27'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code utilises the `dict.get()` method that you use throughout your current code to implement a counter. This is based on reading the values from your current `.txt` file but you could simply bypass the write to file and subsequent read using a similar method.

```
tally = {}

with open('country_codes.txt', 'r') as infile, open('condensed.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        data = line.strip('\n')
        tag1, code, tag2, num = data.split()
        tally[code] = tally.get(code, 0) + int(num)
    for key, value in tally.items(): # Use .iteritems() for Python 2.x
        outfile.write(' '.join(map(str, [key, value, '\n'])))
```

This will take a file (`country_codes.txt`) with this structure:

```
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 2673
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 23
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 459
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 346
code: RO-B, jobs: 9
code: DE-NW, jobs: 4
code: DE-BW, jobs: 3
code: DE-BY, jobs: 9
code: DE-HH, jobs: 34
code: DE-BY, jobs: 11
code: BE-BRU, jobs: 27
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 20
```

And write this to `condensed.txt` as follows:

```
DE-BY, 20 
DE-HH, 34 
DE-BW, 3 
DE-NW, 4 
RO-B, 9 
GB-ENG, 3521 
BE-BRU, 27
```

Comment: so then- this is it's own file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Currently I think you're writing the non-condensed output to `phase_ii_output.txt`? Based on _that_ approach, you would have to read the data back in (as I have done here) and process it again to get your desired output. But it wouldn't take much modification to just remove the write to `phase_ii_output.txt` completely. The idea is just to use `tally[code] = tally.get(code, 0) + int(num)` to sum up the jobs

Comment: this said 'dict' has no attribute 'iterItems'

Comment: @s.matthew.english oops, it was changed in Python 3. Change `iteritems()` to just `items()`. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
data = """code: GB-ENG, jobs: 2673
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 23
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 459
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 346
code: RO-B, jobs: 9
code: DE-NW, jobs: 4
code: DE-BW, jobs: 3
code: DE-BY, jobs: 9
code: DE-HH, jobs: 34
code: DE-BY, jobs: 11
code: BE-BRU, jobs: 27
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 20"""


final_data = {}

for code, count in [_.strip('code: ').split(', jobs: ') for _ in data.split('\n')]:
    if code in final_data:
        final_data[code]['amount'] += int(count)

    else:
        final_data[code] = {'amount': int(count)}

for key, value in final_data.items():
    print('code: {}, jobs: {}'.format(key, value['amount']))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys, re
from collections import defaultdict
tally = defaultdict(int)
for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.match(r'^code: (?P<code>\S+), jobs: (?P<jobs>\d+)', line).groupdict()
    tally[match["code"]] += int(match["jobs"])
for code, jobs in tally.iteritems():
    print "{}, {}".format(code, jobs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This assume that you have a countries.txt formatted like

```
code: GB-ENG jobs: 2673
code: GB-ENG jobs: 23
code: GB-ENG jobs: 459
code: GB-ENG jobs: 346
code: RO-B jobs: 9
code: DE-NW jobs: 4
code: DE-BW jobs: 3
code: DE-BY jobs: 9
code: DE-HH jobs: 34
code: DE-BY jobs: 11
code: BE-BRU jobs: 27
code: GB-ENG jobs: 20
```

Code Snippet

```
with open('countries.txt') as input_file, open('phase_ii_output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
            args = []
            dic = {}
            for line in input_file:
                args.append(line.split(" "))
            for n in args:
                key = n[1]
                num = int(n[3].rstrip())
                if key in dic:
                    dic[key] += num
                else:
                    dic[key] = num
            output_file.write(dic)
```

output

```
{'BE-BRU': 27, 'DE-BY': 20, 'DE-NW': 4, 'DE-BW': 3, 'RO-B': 9, 'GB-ENG': 3521, 'DE-HH': 34}
```